# Is the number of solutions of $\phi(x)=n!$ bounded? If yes, what is its bound?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-functions, growth-rate

Pillai showed in 1929 that the function $A(n)$ giving the number solutions of the equation $\phi(x)=n$ is unbounded in (S. Pillai, [On some functions connected with $\varphi(n)$](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1929-04799-2), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 35 (1929), 832–836). I'm interested to know  about bounds on solutions of $\phi(x)=n!$ which is assigned [A055506 in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A055506), where it is claimed that if $\phi(x) = n!$, then $x$ must be a product of primes $p$ such that $p - 1$ divides $n!$. It is unclear to me if this allows me to prove that there are finitely many solutions of the equation $\phi(x) = n!$.  Probably an equivalent question is to ask:  is the number of solutions of $\phi(x)=n!$ bounded?  If yes, what is its bound ?

**Related question**:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3747571/156150

Comment: For any fixed $n$, the number of solutions to $\phi(x)=n!$ is bounded, since $\phi(x)$ tends to infinity. However, this number is probably not bounded independently of $n$.

Comment: Quotes from [A055506](https://oeis.org/A055506) and [A055487](https://oeis.org/A055487) respectively: "All solutions to $\phi(x) = n!$ are in the interval $[n!,(n+1)!]$", and "According to Tattersall, in 1950 H. Gupta showed that $\phi(x) = n!$ is always solvable". The first gives a bound for fixed $n$, while the latter says that there exists a solution for any $n$. (I do not know arguments backing up either claim.)

Comment: Actually Gupta proves that the number of solutions goes to infinity with $n$, see Hansraj Gupta,
The American Mathematical Monthly,
Vol. 57, No. 5 (May, 1950), pp. 326-329.

Comment: Thanks for the reference , I will check it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPD.** Bound simplified.

Here is a constructive bound for the number of solutions to $\phi(x)=m$.

Let $\varphi(a) = m$. If $p^k\mid a$ for some $k\geq 1$, then $p^{k-1}(p-1)\mid m$, and thus $k\leq 1+\frac{\log(m)}{\log(p)}\leq 1+\frac{\log(m)}{\log(2)}$.
Then the number of such $a$ is bounded by
$$\prod_{d\mid m} (2+\frac{\log(m)}{\log(2)}) = (2+\frac{\log(m)}{\log(2)})^{\tau(m)}.$$

For $m>40$, we have $2+\frac{\log(m)}{\log(2)}\leq 2\log(m)$, and thus we generously bound the number of solutions by
$$(2\log(m))^m.$$

Comment: I don't understand the upper bound on E.  The integral from 2 to m is lower bounded by m/log m.  Even if you don't do the integration but estimate the sum over divisors, I am not seeing your power of log as an upper bound.  Gerhard "Am I Adding This Wrong?" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Nice catch! That was the price of blindly copying bounds from Wikipedia (it seems that $\exp(x/2)$ factor is lost in the bounds for $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ there). Anyway, this approach was somewhat overengineered, and I've replaced it with a simpler one.

Comment: Indeed. However you can replace the exponent with 2sqrt(m) , and if you look at divisor pairs, you can make the base smaller also. Gerhard "Likes To Improve Through Simplification" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: I think you also have to worry about one divisor of m corresponding to two different primes p. Gerhard "Maybe Leave Exponent At M" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: One divisor cannot correspond to different $p$, since $d$ in my answer essentially stands for $p-1$ (and different divisors give different $p$'s). I did not attempt to make the bound as small as possible -- that's a separate question.

Comment: But phi (27)=phi(19).  How does your enumeration account for cases where 27 "is replaced by " 19 as factors of a potential solution a?  Gerhard "One Divisor Unequals One Prime" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: In your example for $m=18$, $27=3^3$ corresponds to $d=2$ (and exponent 3 from its exponent range), $19$ corresponds to $d=18$. I'm not sure what you mean under "replaced by".

Comment: I am completely misreading your formula. I factor m into components each of the form (p^{k-1})(p-1) and call that component d, and think that each term counts the number of possible p that give rise to the same d.  Until I figure this out, assume we are talking at cross purposes for now.  Gerhard "Needs Some More Head Scratching" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: The bound is certainly overkill. First, it is well known that $n/\varphi(n)=O(\log\log n)$, whence $\varphi(n)\le m\implies n=O(m\log\log m)$. Even better, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Totient_numbers) cites a result that $|\{n:\varphi(n)\le m\}|=O(m)$. In fact, the expression given there implies $|\{n:\varphi(n)=m\}|=O\bigl(m(\log m)^{-k}\bigr)$ for all constant $k$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Of course, it's an overkill. My goal was to give a simple self-contained argument for bounding the number of solutions.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: The product here is taken over all $d=p-1\mid m$ for candidate primes $p$ (and possibly some composites), where the product terms are the upper bound for the number of possible exponents. I believe you think more of the bound ala [A045778](https://oeis.org/A045778)(m), which needs to account for existence of multiple primepower preimages of the same number. My approach is free from this issue.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev It’s easy to give a simple self-contained argument for bounds much closer to optimal. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler bound, based on the comment of R. van Dobben de Bruyn.

Let a solution of the equation be broken into two parts, c and d, where c is the n-smooth part of the solution, and is coprime to d, which of necessity is square free and has all prime factors bigger than n. (I leave the case n=1 to the reader.)  Then c is at most n! (2/1)(3/2)(5/4)...((n+1)/n)which for n greater than three is strictly less than (n+1)n!. So c is less than (n+1)! .

Turning to d, each prime divisor of d contributes at least one power of 2 when subject to Euler's phi, so d has fewer than n prime divisors. So d is less than e times n!.

Since the shrinkage under phi of the product is at most e(n+1), the original solution must be less than 3(n+1)!.  This is also a weak upper bound on the total number of solutions, but can probably be improved to show that the number  and location of solutions generally is less than (n+1)!, leaving the case of small n to the reader where all creation (counterexamples, arrghh spellcheck!) must lie.

**Edit 2020.07.09. GRP:**

The argument above for bounding $n$ given $m=\phi(n)$ is made even simpler, as $ n/\phi(n)$ is a product of
$k$ many terms of the form $p/(p-1)$ where the $p$ are distinct primes.  This bounded above by $(2/1)(3/2 )(5/3)...$, which for all $k$ is less than $k+1$ and for large $k$ grows like $\log k$. Since $k$ is bounded by a function smaller than $\log m$, we can get an upper bound on $n$ that looks like $Cm\log\log m$, likely for $C$ less than 4.  Even when $k$ is large, $n$ can't have many more distinct primes than powers of 2 dividing $m$.

Towards the original question, note that there are easy solutions of totient value being a factorial, and that some of them can be extended by replacing certain powers of small primes by a prime $q$ such that $q$ is bigger than the base of the factorial and such that $q-1$ equals the powers of the small primes and $q$ is not already a prime factor of the solution being modified.
Thus it seems very likely that the number of solutions is not bounded as the size of the factorial grows.

**End Edit 2020.07.09. GRP.**

Gerhard "Leaving Hard Work To Others" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: If we let k be the exponent of the exact power of two dividing m, we get that any solution to the general equation must (for k not too small) be less than 3(k+1)m, giving a weak but non exponential (in m) upper bound on the number of solutions.  Gerhard "Really Likes This Re-engineering Stuff" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Comment: Toward a lower bound, which is the main thrust of the question. Note first that for P the product of the primes at most n one has $\phi((n!)P/\phi(P))=n!$ and one has an alternate representation when n+1 is an odd prime.   There also is a representation involving a prime q bigger than n whenever $\phi(q)$ divides $n!/(P\phi(P))$.  Proving the existence of $q$ for every sufficiently large n should show the number of solutions grows without bound as $n$ grows.  Gerhard "Is Almost Convinced Of Unboundedness" Paseman, 2020.07.07.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\frac n{\varphi(n)}=\prod_{p\mid n}\bigl(1-p^{-1}\bigr)^{-1}
\le2\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\ge3}}\frac32
=2\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\ge3}}3^{\log_3(3/2)}
\le2\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\ge3}}p^{\log_3(3/2)}
\le2n^{\log_3(3/2)}$$
(where $p$ runs over primes), hence
$$\varphi(n)\le m\implies n\le(2m)^{(1-\log_3(3/2))^{-1}}=(2m)^{\log_23}.$$
Using a larger cut-off $k$ in place of $3$, the same argument gives
$$\varphi(n)\le m\implies n\le(c_km)^{\log_{k-1}k},$$
where
$$c_k=\prod_{p<k}\bigl(1-p^{-1}\bigr)^{-1}.$$
Notice that $\log_{k-1}k\approx1+\frac1{k\log k}$ for large $k$.

I will not go into details, but it is easy to prove by well-known elementary arguments that $c_k=O(\log k)$, hence if we choose $k\approx\log m$, we obtain
$$\varphi(n)\le m\implies n\le c\,m\log\log m$$
for some constant $c$.

Comment: The nice idea you have used is the compositional inverse of Euler totiont function

Comment: Um, the argument I present above can be adapted to show that phi(n)=m implies n is at most (k+1)m, where k is the exponent of 2 that divides m.  When m has many prime factors, this can be changed to ( Clog k) m using work of Mertens or simpler approximations.  Gerhard "Not Quite Gilding The Lily" Paseman, 2020.07.09.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I have no idea what all this talk about lilies is about, but did I just see you include parts of my answer in your answer without as much as a thank you?

Comment: I think this could blow up into a major misunderstanding if we aren't careful.  It is not clear to me what part for which you want credit.  However, the edit I made to my post has an argument similar to the one in my original post.  If you need recognition, I need to know more precisely for what.  I thought the product over primes had too generous a bound in the first part of your post. Gerhard "Not In It For Points" Paseman, 2020.07.09.

Comment: If you want credit for writing n/\phi(n), I am willing to recognize you as a recent source of inspiration.  Gerhard "Will That Help This Situation?" Paseman, 2020.07.09.

Comment: @Gerhard The argument in my answer is extremely simple, hence it is no doubt “similar” to any other argument estimating $\varphi(n)$, such as the one in your answer. Nevertheless, the first paragraph you added basically copies what I already wrote, yielding the same $O(m\log\log m)$ bound, and I find this rather uncool. And yes, one of the points of my answer is that even though the bound on the product looks generous, it leads to the same asymptotic estimate as if it were bounded in a more complicated way, which is why I did the simple way.

Comment: I hope to avoid a misunderstanding. If by first paragraph of my answer you mean of my post, that appeared a day before your post. (I leave the ramifications of this unstated.) If you instead mean first paragraph of the edit, indeed some of it was inspired by the first paragraph of my answer and by the first line of your answer, where n/\phi(n) appears.  However your simple argument giving a fractional exponent bound does not appear as simple to me as the one that gives a logarithmic (in m) bound on the multiplier.  Gerhard "Please Add Clarity To Comment" Paseman, 2020.07.10.